# Forwards/Backwards navigation links dying after repetitive use

Tags: html

I'm writing a website using HTML5 and I have a problem trying to use unordered lists in order to navigate through the site. The problem code is below:

```
<ul>
      <li>
<a href="furtherexercises.html">Home</a></a>
      </li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="furtherexercisepage2.html">Webpage validation</a></li>
</ul>
```

The links `<a href="furtherexercises.html">` and `<a href="furtherexercisepage2.html">` are local files stored in my `Z://` drive, along with the rest of the website files.

Let's call the Home page "Page 1" and the website validation page "Page 2":

*When testing the website using CoffeeCup's 'browser test' feature, I can navigate from page 1 to page 2 but when I return to page 1, the link to page 2 is dead, likewise when testing Page 2 I can navigate to page 1 but not back to Page 2.
It is not that I can click the link but receive a 'Page not found' error or otherwise, *but the link itself literally does not exist on the page.*
 I've noticed the URL's are different when I travel through the pages...

Page 1 Original URL: `file:///Z:/test/~tm941C.html`

Page 2 URL after following hyperlink: `file:///Z:/test/furtherexercisepage2.html`

Page 1 URL after following hyperlink from Page 2 `file:///Z:/test/furtherexercises.html`

**Concise routes: Page 1 --> Page 2 --> HyperLink to page 1 not on site.**

**Page 2 --> Page 1 -- HyperLink to page 2 not on site**

Is there any way I can modify this so that I can navigate forwards and backwards between Page 1 and 2 without the link disappearing from the site?

EDIT: a few people have noticed a syntax error whereby I have an extra anchor tag. To prevent this remission happening in future I am going to use the W3C webpage validator: [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org). This acts as a peer reviewer in a way, highlighting errors in your code. It may help with your webpages if you weren’t already aware of this tool.

Comment: Extra anchor ending tag, probably a result of auto complete

Comment: @Huangism Quite possibly the case - as below. I will remove the tag tomorrow when I’m at work and see if anything happens. Next time I’m just going to use the W3C validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra anchor tag.

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="furtherexercises.html">Home</a></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The link to 'furtherexercises.html' should only be closed once. This may be causing a problem.

Comment: Good spot! I will try this tomorrow morning when I am back at work and let you know if it works.

Comment: That did it, problem solved. Next time I'll just use validator.w3.org first before I ask on this site - assumed the issue wouldn't be down to syntax. Schoolboy!